# How to apply joint query in sequelize

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Project.model.ts

```
import { DataTypes, Model, CreationOptional, InferCreationAttributes, InferAttributes, BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin, BelongsToManySetAssociationsMixin, BelongsToManyAddAssociationsMixin } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../../loaders/db'; // config of sequelize
import Manager from '../manager/manager.model';

const tableName = 'project';

export interface ProjectModel extends Model<InferAttributes<ProjectModel>, InferCreationAttributes<ProjectModel>>  {
  id:  CreationOptional<number>;
  name: string;
  managerId: number | null;
}

const Project = sequelize().define<ProjectModel>(
  tableName,
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    managerId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Manager, // Reference Manager model
        key: 'id',
      },
      field: 'conformance_id',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

export default Project;
```

Page.model.ts

```
import { DataTypes, Model, CreationOptional, InferCreationAttributes, InferAttributes, BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin, BelongsToManySetAssociationsMixin, BelongsToManyAddAssociationsMixin } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../../loaders/db'; // config of sequelize
import Project from '../project/project.model';

const tableName = 'page';

export interface PageModel extends Model<InferAttributes<PageModel>, InferCreationAttributes<PageModel>> {
  id: CreationOptional<number>;
  projectId: number; // Foreign key to link with the Project model
  name: string;
}

const Page = sequelize().define<PageModel>(
  tableName,
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    projectId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Project, // Reference Project model
        key: 'id',
      },
      field: 'project_id'
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true,
      field: 'name'
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

export default Page;
```

Manager.model.ts

```
import { DataTypes, Model, CreationOptional, InferCreationAttributes, InferAttributes, BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin, BelongsToManySetAssociationsMixin, BelongsToManyAddAssociationsMixin } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../../loaders/db'; // config of sequelize

const tableName = 'manager';

export interface ManagerModel extends Model<InferAttributes<ManagerModel>, InferCreationAttributes<ManagerModel>> {
  id: CreationOptional<number>;
  level: string; // Foreign key to link with the Project model
  name: string;
}

const Manager = sequelize().define<ManagerModel>(
  tableName,
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    level: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(10),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true,
      field: 'name'
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

export default Manager;
```

Project.service.ts

```
import { Service } from 'typedi';
import Project from './project.model';

@Service()
export default class ProjectService {
  async getProjectById(id: string) {
    try {
      const project = await Project.findOne({
        where: { id },
        // remaining part of the query to get manager and page details using any operator
      });
      if (!project) {
        throw new Error('Project not found');
      }
      return project;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch Project by ID');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm new to this Sequelize. Now I'm not sure what kinda query I have to add Project.findOne() method. I need name of the manager name from manager table and pages array associate with that project. Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Did you deifned associationd between models like `Project.belongsTo(Manager ...` or `Project.hasMany(Page,...`?

Comment: @Anatoly, Nope, I haven't define belongTo and hasMany for model. I believe that is it'll create another tables to maintain the relation between project and manage as well as project and pages. But I'll willing to see your solution over here. What kinda relations I have to add using belongsTo and hasMany for these models. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Look at https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/ first and try it and if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an (untested) example using `include` to specify the associated models (Manager and Page) along with the attributes to be included in the result. So this should fetch a project along with manager's name and array of associated pages.

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
import Project from './project.model';
import Manager from '../manager/manager.model';
import Page from '../page/page.model';

@Service()
export default class ProjectService {
  async getProjectById(id: string) {
    try {
      const project = await Project.findOne({
        where: { id },
        include: [
          {
            model: Manager,
            attributes: ['name'], // Include only the 'name' attribute of the Manager model
          },
          {
            model: Page,
            attributes: ['name'], // Include only the 'name' attribute of the Page model
          },
        ],
      });
      if (!project) {
        throw new Error('Project not found');
      }
      return project;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch Project by ID');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Adrain Maxwell, nope this isn't working. And TBH I have already tried this solution but include is not working. {"level":"error","message":"Failed to fetch Project by ID","stack":"Error: Failed to fetch Project by ID"}. It's giving error like this one if I add include part in query. Without that it's working perfectly but obviously it's not giving another table data.